# Converting dataframe into dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, data-structures

I have a dataframe with three columns containing 220 datapoints. Now I need to make one column the key and the other column the value and remove the third column. How do I do that?

I have created the dataframe by scraping Wikipedia in order to create a Keyword Search. Now I need to create an index of terms contained, for which dictionaries are the most effective. How do I create a dictionaries out of a dataframe where one column in the key for another column?

Comment: You can create and apply a `lambda` function to create key value pairs from that dataframe and append in a dictionary.

Comment: New to Lambda and Python. Can you give me an example

Comment: @AchyuthN Can you please share a sample input and expected output?

Answer (score 0):

I have used a sample dataframe having 3 columns and 3 rows as you have not provided the actual data. You can replace it with your data and column names.

I have used for loop with iterrows() to loop over each row.

Code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame (
    {'Alphabet': ['A', 'B','C'] ,
     'Number': [1,2,3],
     'To_Remove': [10, 15, 8]})

sample_dictionary = {}


for index,row in df.iterrows():
    sample_dictionary[row['Alphabet']] = row['Number']

print(sample_dictionary)
```

Output:

```
{'A': 1, 'B': 2, 'C': 3}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Pandas function,
**pd.Dataframe.to_dict**

Documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html

**Example**

```
import pandas as pd

# Original dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 2, 3],
                  'col2': [0.5, 0.75, 1.0],
                   'col3':[0.1, 0.9, 1.9]},
                  index=['a', 'b', 'c'])

# To dictonary
dictionary = df.to_dict(df)
```